# displaying SQLite database as application is running in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i have created a database using `SQliteCursor` in android. but non of my queries work and it always give me no such table exception.so i want to see the database to check if it is even created?! 
so here is my question:how can i see my created database with code as the program is running???

I saw so many answers but they all assume there is a database in DDMS perspective.
is there any tool I can use? what can I do?
besides I am using cursor to enter queries.
thanks.

Comment: Try [Android SQLite Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xuecs.sqlitemanager&hl=en)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pull the database from the device to your local disk by executing following commands:
First make your database file accessible by running chmod using run-as command of adb

```
adb shell "run-as package.name chmod 666 /data/data/package.name/databases/file"
```

Then try to pull that file in your local disk

```
adb pull /data/data/package.name/databases/file
```

Just make sure that you have marked the application to debuggable=true in the manifest.
To view this database you can download a mozilla plugin i.e SqliteManager and can view the full schema of DB. I always use this and it is really good.

I made a executable file  for this process please add below lines in a file with .exe or sh extension depending on your system OS:

`adb shell "run-as yourpackagename chmod 666 databases/yourdbname.db"
adb shell "cp /data/data/yourpackagename/databases/yourdbname.db /sdcard/"
adb shell "run-as yourpackagename chmod 600 databases/yourdbname.db"
adb pull /sdcard/yourdbname.db`

Replace yourdbname with your Db name and yourpackagename  with the package name of your app.
Please post if you got stuck somewhere in the steps.

Comment: it says package unknown and file does not exists

Answer (score 0):

Please paste some code for better understanding.

or try this

Go to DDMS => data => data => here you have to find your project like com.example.example. In this you will easily get database file and you can save it or check whether it is created or not.